# Checking if value exists in SQLite table using Python while statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sqlite

I am trying to create a function that will generate a tag that does not already exist in an sqlite table. Here is what I have thus far:

```
def generateTag(type):

    elementTag = ""

    charSet = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
               "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h",
               "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q",
               "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
               "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",
               "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
               "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

    centralDBInfo = Describe(centralDBName)
    rowAmount = [int(i[2]) for i in centralDBInfo]

    while True:
        for n in range (100):
            if 62**n < rowAmount[0] or n <= 1:
                for x in range(n):
                    randomSelection = numpy.random.randint(0,62)
                    elementTag += str(charSet[randomSelection])
                break

        tagQuery = "SELECT * FROM {t}_Base WHERE {et} EXISTS".format(t = type, et = elementTag)
        rowFetch = centralCursor.execute(tagQuery)

        if rowFetch == None:
            return elementTag
```

As you can see, it is pretty nested in some places, but I believe it will do the job just fine. However, something about it seems logically flawed, but I just can't put my finger on it. I will explain my reasoning for some of the ambiguous things you see in the code below:

- The Describe function returns a tuple list with [(tableName, numberOfColumns, numberOfRows, numberOfCells)]
- I am selecting from {t}_base because I literally have a table for each datatype in my centralDB
- I use (62**n < rowAmount[0]) to determine if the preceding values in the table have already taken up all possible arrangements of charset (62 value list) for the length of elementTag over the current iteration.

Please ask me if you have any more questions or comments.

Comment: did you get any error or something? Btw you don't need the `tagExists` variable. Another thing I see is you are computing `64**n` repeatedly.

Comment: No I haven't gotten any errors because CentralDB is not yet populated. Don't I need tagExists so that it will try creating another tag if the prior tag already exists? Also, I am repeatedly calculating 64**n because n increments until 100.

Comment: You are returning as soon as you get None which means `tagExists` is never set to false explicitly. It being always true, you don't need that. You can just do `while True:`. You are calling `64**n` again and again because of that outer while loop.

Comment: Check out my edit. Do you think that would work?

Comment: Last thing I think is, in the worst case, you should probably stop that outer while loop sometime. It just doesn't look nice. What is `rowAmount[0]` ? Because you are comparing 100 values with a single variable.

Comment: It might be faster and simpler to select each existing tag in order and fill in the gaps. Or delete all rows and insert every tag. Some more solid information about this table and what's in it would help.